# Oracle Database XE 11.2 - Create Database

Tags: database, oracle

I have finally, after hours of messing about, finally managed to install Oracle Express edition. I now need to create a very basic Database with one table which has just 3 fields within it. However I have no experience with Oracle only MySQL and therefore have no idea where to start.

At the moment all I have managed to do is view "something" at: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950`

Can someone point me in the right direction to creating this?

Comment: Try to accept some replies as answer if they help.

Answer (score 2):

When you installed XE.... it automatically created a database called "XE".   You can use your login "system" and password that you set to login.

Key info

server: (you defined)
port: 1521
database: XE
username: system
password: (you defined)

Oh yeah, basically Oracle is being difficult and won't let you easily create multiple databases.   You have to use SQL or a tool to create another database besides "XE"

Answer (score 0):

It is oracle APEX. here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AclUZCtgrKY) for creating tables in APEX.

Alternatively,

You can use [SQLPLUS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus). It is included in the Oracle package. Or better, download Oracle [SQLDEVELOPER](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), which is a free ide for Oracle development.

After this, login with the username and password which you should have configured during the installation.

Later you can create a new user (optional but recommended) and create the table you want. Just Google for creating Oracle tables.